# NSUnknownKeyException for the new view

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

i m using this in learncontroller.h

```
IBOutlet  UIView    *splashView;
```

and also

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *splashView;
```

and in .m on next button clik

```
[splashView setTag:1000];
[self.view addSubview:splashView];
```

So from here when i move to next view called view01
IT says

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<View01 0x56816c0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key splashView.'
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [This class is not key value coding-compliant for the key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088059/this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant-for-the-key)

Answer (score 0):

Either you forgot to connect this in you nib file as it is declare as IBOutlet, Or you have done some mistake in copy pasting your code from one place to another (may be you forgot to copy .xib file with .h and .m file)

Comment: no In XIB ther is 2 views1>View and 2>splashview so i connect the splashview to fileowner

Comment: file Owner should be connected to view and other view should be connected to splashView